Strange blue/green seam between skin materials
I've tried researching this issue as it is sometimes a recurring problem for me but I can't seem to find a forum or answer for it anywhere. With some models I work with I get odd green and/or blue lines along areas with different materials even if the coloring matches. My best guess was a subsurface glitch, but that doesn't seem to be the case unless I am wrong. Is there any way to prevent this that I am not aware of?

I have seen something like this before and there the reason was an inner face between the head and the body. But without the file I cannot tell.
